# Add custom user attribute to claims of user flow in Azure AD B2C via graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

**I created user custom attribute via graph api in my azure active directory B2C and now I want to add it to the claims of the token for specific user flows**.

Of course I want to do this via graph too and it would be the best to have example which use Graph SDK but Graph API is ok too. Does anyone know how to do it?

Just to be sure that you understand me. I want to achieve via graph the same what we can achieve going to the azure poral -> b2c -> user flows -> (select flow) -> application claims -> (select and add custom attribute).

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available yet. As of today, you can use Graph api to add user attributes as attribute but not as a claim.

Comment: I think it is possible by creating custom policy but I'm working on it

Comment: Custom policies support Microsoft Graph operations, so you can do anything there. user flows don't have all operations as of now. Your question was specific to user flows

Comment: @freak_geek
Did you found a solution?

Comment: @KondzioSSJ4 as it was said, you need to search for custom policies